# Target a specific div to scroll even outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I point the mouse within the div tag, the scrolling works, however I can't scroll the content if I point the mouse outside the box of div. Is it possible to target a specific div wherever the mouse pointer goes?

```html
<div style="max-height: 100px;overflow-y: scroll;">
  TEST<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```js
const target = document.getElementById("target");

document.addEventListener("wheel", function(e){
  // prevent the default scrolling event
  e.preventDefault();

  // scroll the div
  target.scrollBy(e.deltaX, e.deltaY);
})
```

```css
#target{
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">
  TEST<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register the event by yourselves. Such that you can scroll the `div` you want outside the `div`.

Those this will be tedious for you to handle if your page has multiple scroller.

By the way, to make it a bit more pretty, you need to add animation or it will move 'discretely' as following shown.

```js
document.getElementById("scroll").addEventListener("wheel", e=>e.preventDefault());
document.getElementById("main").addEventListener("wheel", e=>myFunction(e));

function myFunction(e) {
    document.getElementById("scroll").scrollTop += 0.2 * e.deltaY;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" style="height:300px">
<div id="scroll" style="max-height: 100px;overflow-y: scroll;">
  TEST<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I might use your method in another cases (if I wrap the `id="scroll"`).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to target a specific div wherever the mouse pointer goes?

Not really... what you probably want to do instead is to set other parts of the page to `position: fixed` or `position: sticky`.  This way the main body content will scroll but some parts will remain in the same place.  Stack Overflow itself does this with the top header and the left sidebar.